# Will a USB 2.0 LAN Adapter work with interrupts instead of polling if i plug it on a USB 3.0 port?

Tags: lan, network-adapter, usb-3, usb-2, interrupts

I have a LAN Adapter (HORI LAN Adapter for Nintendo Switch) that has the ASIX AX88179 USB 3.0 chipset, but it's USB 2.0.

(I checked the cable plug and it doesn't have the USB 3.0's extra pins, also USBView of WindowsSDK reports that the device is SuperSpeed capable, but it always works at High-Speed interface even being plugged on a USB 3.0 port)

My question is, will my LAN Adapter have the benefits of USB 3.0 like interrupts instead of polling (less latency) and DMA for less CPU load having a USB 3.0 chipset but being on USB 2.0 interface? Or it will work the same as having a USB 2.0 adapter with a ASIX AX88178A?

Comment: Have you performed any benchmarks? e.g: `iperf` for AX88179 vs a true USB 2.0 chipset. I suspect the results will be quite telling.

Comment: Hi, I don't have a real USB 2.0 lan adapter, but I did an Iperf test with a true USB 3.0 LAN Adapter connected to another Laptop with Gigabit LAN using a CAT5e ethernet cable and I got more or less 600Mbps (I don't remember the exact number, but I'm pretty sure it did exceed the USB 2.0 theorical maximum).
The Hori LAN Adapter in comparison with the same computer and same cable performed 360Mbps.
Anyway, my question is not for the bandwidth since my connection is 30Mbps which is enough for USB2, I wanted to know about Interrupts and DMA being possible on the Hori adapter being USB2.